# Number of unique ways to connect two ordered lists of integers

Tags: combinatorics

## Problem description

There are two ordered lists of integers of equal length `A` and `B`.
Every element in `A` has to be connected to exactly one element in `B` and every element in `B` has to be connected to exactly one element in `A` such that `b >= a` for every pair of elements `a in A` and `b in B`.

that is equal or larger than itself.

Now I would like to know how many unique ways we can connect the elements of `A` and `B`.

Naively, one can just go through all possible options which will result in an algorithm that scales with `n!` with `n` being the length of `A` and `B`. `n!` is also the upper limit for the number of unique connections.
I am looking for an algorithm that is more performant (and ideally linear in `n`).

## Examples

### Example 1

`A = [1, 2]` and `B = [2, 3]` there are 2 ways

- 1-2, 2-3
- 1-3, 2-2

### Example 2

`A = [1, 2, 3]` and `B = [3, 4, 5]` there are 6 ways

- 1-3, 2-4, 3-5
- 1-3, 2-5, 2-4
- 1-4, 2-3, 3-5
- 1-4, 2-5, 3-3
- 1-5, 2-3, 3-4
- 1-5, 2-4, 3-3

This solution is just `3 * 2 * 1 = 3!`.

### Example 3

`A = [1, 2, 2, 4]` and `B = [2, 4, 4, 5]` there are 5 ways

- 1-2, 2-4, 2-4, 4-5
- 1-2, 2-4, 2-4, 4-4
- 1-4, 2-2, 2-4, 4-5
- 1-4, 2-2, 2-5, 4-4
- 1-5, 2-2, 2-4, 4-4

Comment: Example 3 is invalid as *sets* do not have multiple elements.  (Also sets do not have "length" they have size).   If you are thinking of *lists* that can have multiple elements, you also have to worry about order as lists have order and the list $1,2,2,4$ is not the same list as $1,4,2,4$. (sets do not have order)

Comment: There are just too many ways the elements of the sets can overlap to make any simple formula reasonable.  But you could do something recursive on the various ways to add one element to sets on which the answer is known.

Comment: @fleablood, you are right. I changed the description from set to "ordered list"

Comment: In example 1: Why is 1-3, 2-3 not an option? Every element in $A$ is connected to exactly one element in $B$. Do you also want each element in $B$ to be connected to by at most one element in $A$ or every element in $B$ actually connected to? Similarly you could also do 1-2, 2-2? right?

Comment: @N8tron, exactly. I have edited the description.

Comment: I find it a little odd that repeated values like the 4's in $B$ in example 4 are treated as distinct for the purpose of connecting but not in terms of the counting the number of them. For example you counted 1-2, 2-4, 2-4, 4-5 once. But you could make a case that B[1]=4 and B[2]=4. So why not count 1-2. 2-B[1], 2-B[2], 4-5 and  1-2. 2-B[2], 2-B[1], 4-5  as distinct options?

Comment: This seems related to Juggling Drops & Descents which does try to count certain periodic versions of this when both $A$ and $B$ are the integers. Probably not that useful in this case, but you may find it interesting http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/buhler/paper/html/paper.html

Comment: This problem is related to a more complicated one where I want to count valid substrings. This is why multiple copies of the same number count for the purpose of connecting but not when counting them.